# Need help setting subject with the switch function

Tags: php, validation

I'm updating my post since I still haven't solved it yet with my new code, using switch function. I want the user to be able to select from a drop down a contact and that selection set the subject as well. As of now I keep getting the default instead of case 1 or 2.

```
<?php
//PHP Mail Form
function sanstr($value)
{
$value = strip_tags($value);
$value = trim($value);
$value = escapeshellcmd($value);
$value = htmlentities($value);

return $value;
}

$errorMessage = array();
switch ($to) 
{
case "1":
$to = "example1@example.com";
$subject = "Subject 1";
break;
case "2":
$to = "example2@example.com";
$subject = "Subject 2";
break;
default:
$to = "example@example.com";
$subject = "Default";
break;
{

if(isset($_POST['form']))
{
$formData = $_POST['form'];

if (filter_var($formData['from'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $from = sanitizeString($formData['from']);
}
else
{
    $errorMessage[] = "Please use a valid email format: name@domain.com";
}

if(strlen($formData['name']) > 0)
{
    $name = sanitizeString($formData['name']);
}
else
{
    $errorMessage[] = "Please enter your name.";
}

if(strlen($formData['title']) > 0)
{
    $title = sanitizeString($formData['title']);
}
else
{
    $title = '';
}

if(strlen($formData['company']) > 0)
{
    $company = sanitizeString($formData['company']);
}
else
{
    $company = '';
}

if(strlen($formData['phone']) > 0)
{
    $phone = sanitizeString($formData['phone']);
}
else
{
    $errorMessage[] = "Please enter a phone number.";
}

if(strlen($formData['message']) > 0)
{
    $message = sanitizeString($formData['message']);
}
else
{
    $errorMessage[] = 'Cannot leave message box blank.';
}

if (empty($errorMessage))
{
    $email_headers = "From:" . $from . "\nMIME-Version: 1.0 \nContent-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    $message_send = "<h3>" . $name . "<br>" . $title . "<br>" . $company . "<br>" . $phone . "<br>" . $from . "</h3><hr><h4>" . $subject . "</h4>" . $message;

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message_send, $email_headers))
    {
        $errorMessage[] = 'Thank you, your email is on the way!';
    }
    else
    {
        $errorMessage[] = 'There seems to be a problem!';
    }
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have received help for this problem. I am posting the code that solved the problem here if anyone needs something like this.

```
<?php
//Sainitize function
function sanitizeString($value){
$value = strip_tags($value);
$value = trim($value);
$value = escapeshellcmd($value);
$value = htmlentities($value);

return $value;
}

//Receivers
$receivers = array();
//IF built with query put email as key, subject as value in loop or specify like below
$receivers['default@example.com']  = 'Default Subject';
$receivers['example1@example.com'] = 'Subject 1';
$receivers['example2@example.com'] = 'Subject 2';



$errorMessage = array();

if(isset($_POST['form'])){
$formData = $_POST['form'];

if (filter_var($formData['from'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $from = sanitizeString($formData['from']);
}else{
    $errorMessage[] = "Please use a valid email format: name@domain.com";
}

if(strlen($formData['to']) > 0){
    $to = sanitizeString($formData['to']);
}else{
    $to = 'example@example.com';
}

if(strlen($formData['name']) > 0){
    $name = sanitizeString($formData['name']);
}else{
    $errorMessage[] = "Please enter your name.";
}

if(strlen($formData['title']) > 0){
    $title = sanitizeString($formData['title']);
}else{
    $title = '';
}

if(strlen($formData['company']) > 0){
    $company = sanitizeString($formData['company']);
}else{
    $company = '';
}

if(strlen($formData['phone']) > 0){
    $phone = sanitizeString($formData['phone']);
}else{
    $errorMessage[] = "Please enter a phone number.";
}

if(strlen($formData['message']) > 0){
    $message = sanitizeString($formData['message']);
}else{
    $errorMessage[] = 'Cannot leave message box blank.';
}

if (empty($errorMessage) && $formData['message']){        

if(strlen($formData['subject']) > 0){
        $subject = sanitizeString($formData['subject']);
}else{
        $subject = $receivers[$to];
}

$email_headers = "From:" . $from . "\nMIME-Version: 1.0 \nContent-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
$message_send = "<h3>" . $name . "<br>" . $title . "<br>" . $company . "<br>" . $phone . "<br>" . $from . "</h3><hr><h4>" . $subject . "</h4>" . $message;

if (mail($to, $subject, $message_send, $email_headers)){
        $errorMessage[] = 'Thank you, your email is on the way!';
}else{
        $errorMessage[] = 'There seems to be a problem!';
    }
}
}

?>
```

Thanks to everyone that tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rework of your if/elseif/else statements the second block of code in your question:

```
if (strlen($formData['subject']) > 0)
{
    $subject = sanitizeString($formData['subject']);
}
elseif ($receivers == "1")
{
    $subject = "Subject 1";

}
elseif ($receivers == "2")
{
    $subject = "Subject 2";
}
else
{
    $subject = "Default";
}
```

I added a default in case none of the conditions are met.  In this case, you might also look at the *Switch* statement, which is more efficient if you have several alternates.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I updated my code to include the switch function. Now the only problem I have is that it sends the default instead of case 1 or 2. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again for your earlier suggestion.